# Forming UI Kit search JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to add a search bar to a [UI Kit](http://getuikit.com) template. I have a JSON file that I want PHP to parse to only show a subset of the JSON file.

I have an example of what the JSON code needs to look like: [Example](http://getuikit.com/src/tests/addons/_searchautocomplete.json)

```
<?php
        $json = json_encode(array(
            "results" => array(
                array(
                    "title" => "Google",
                    "url" => "http://google.com",
                    "text" => "A large search engine"),
                array(
                    "title" => "Microsoft",
                    "url" => "http://microsoft.com",
                    "text" => "Devices and Services company"),
                array(
                    "title" => "Apple",
                    "url" => "http://apple.com",
                    "text" => "iPad, iPhone, Mac, iOS"),
                array(
                    "title" => "IBM",
                    "url" => "http://ibm.com",
                    "text" => "Innovators of hardware and software")
            )
        ));

        $_REQUEST['search'] = $json;
?>
```

I've tried several configurations without any luck.

Final Answer:

```
<?php
    if ((isset($_REQUEST['search'])) && (!empty($_REQUEST['search'])))
    {
        $search_field= $_REQUEST['search'];
    }
    $json = json_encode(array(
        "results" => array(
            array(
                "title" => "Google",
                "url" => "http://google.com",
                "text" => "A large search engine"),
            array(
                "title" => "Microsoft",
                "url" => "http://microsoft.com",
                "text" => "Devices and Services company"),
            array(
                "title" => "Apple",
                "url" => "http://apple.com",
                "text" => "iPad, iPhone, Mac, iOS"),
            array(
                "title" => "IBM",
                "url" => "http://ibm.com",
                "text" => "Innovators of hardware and software")
        )
    ));
    echo $json;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want such structure, you may need to remove the sub keys, `google, microsoft, etc..` to make a similar match. Consider this example:

```
$json = json_encode(array(
    "results" => array(
        array(
            "title" => "Google",
            "url" => "http://google.com",
            "text" => "A large search engine"),
        array(
            "title" => "Microsoft",
            "url" => "http://microsoft.com",
            "text" => "Devices and Services company"),
        array(
            "title" => "Apple",
            "url" => "http://apple.com",
            "text" => "iPad, iPhone, Mac, iOS"),
        array(
            "title" => "IBM",
            "url" => "http://ibm.com",
            "text" => "Innovators of hardware and software")
    )
), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($json);
echo '</pre>';
```

This yields something like:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "title": "Google",
            "url": "http://google.com",
            "text": "A large search engine"
        },
        {
            "title": "Microsoft",
            "url": "http://microsoft.com",
            "text": "Devices and Services company"
        },
        {
            "title": "Apple",
            "url": "http://apple.com",
            "text": "iPad, iPhone, Mac, iOS"
        },
        {
            "title": "IBM",
            "url": "http://ibm.com",
            "text": "Innovators of hardware and software"
        }
    ]
}
```

Similar to your link. Try to remove the sub keys.

Comment: Thank you, I think that should be good for the array itself. I'm having a trouble implementing the php file in the first place, was told to use $_REQUEST but I hear that's bad. [Github Issues Page](https://github.com/uikit/uikit/issues/412)

Comment: @user3713187 i think you're returning it wrong, you do not need to use `$_REQUEST[]`. just put `header('Content-Type: application/json');` above the php, then just `echo $json;`. I think that ui kit search feature will be able to use it that way

Comment: I can't plus 1 you because I'm still <15 reputation points, but you are absolutely correct! Thanks for that help Kevin!